# Change default alignment type-on-a-path on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have to name some lines in a mathematical plot and using the type on the path tool seems to be the perfect choice, however for some reason Illustrator draws the values backwards. Check the picture:
[image]

As you can see, the 1000 line is aligned "backwards", and my interest is to align it as the 900 value. Now I can do that dragging the handlers, or using the Type on a Path tool Options, but is there a way to change the default alignment as it is very difficult to do each one individually as there are around 200 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue with strokes. I use inside aligned strokes almost exclusively. The default is align to center. There are some things that work by defining a custom template in illustrator (such as the default color swatches). You basically do a template, save it, and when File-New, you select that template and start off with those things already present in your document.

But these "settings" are pretty much oblivious to customization. You will need to use the direct selection tool to drag the *handle* upward because there is really no setting that tells Illustrator which way is up or down.

Imagine typing on a circle. In the upper half it's up, in the lower half it's upside down. :)

Best of luck to you!

Comment: Heh yeah, thanks. Pretty much that seems to be the case. I've been able however to figure out a small hack that does the job. I used 'Character Rotation' to rotate to 180 deg, and write the number backwards so lets say I want to write 730, i would write 037. It's bad, but might be helpful if someone needs to write all the lines.

Comment: That's actually kind of neat!